# Verify Kernel Boot Parameters

Tags: linux, kernel

Long story short, I'd like to verify that Centos actually booted / used the kernel flags/parameters I specified in /etc/grub.conf

Is there a command I can type that will show me details on the kernel that is presently running (INCLUDING the paramaters that are enabled)?

uname -a only shows the versions and hostnames.

Thanks,

M

Comment: You should probably edit this question, and remove all of the Centos stuff. I'd do it, but not enough exp. This solved my problem too.

Comment: @Evan Done. I still left the CentOS part in the question body but made the tag and topic more generic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cat /proc/cmdline